# Google Map and custom marker for current location

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I am building an application that will show markers on a Google Map based on where a user is currently located. However I'm finding the Documentation on the Google site rather confusing and I don't really know where best to start with this.

I want to create a custom marker where the user is located in the form of small icon and then show above it a small popup that when hovered will say something like 'you're here'. e.g. [image]

I have the following code so far to create a google map and get the user location. So how would I say (basing this on Foursquare) show the blue marker:[image] where the location is and then position a popup above it with a small avatar inside e.g. [image] it becomes like so: [image]

My Google code so far is:

http://jsfiddle.net/dnzZd/

If anyone can help me get in the right direction I would very much appreciate it thanks. I'm very good at HTML and CSS so would be able to easily create the style and look I want (if GMaps even relies on CSS) it's just a case of getting it on the screen and understanding more of how this works.

Thanks to all who can help.

Answer (score 7):

Based on the [documentation](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays.html#Markers) here and this [working sample](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/icon-simple.html).

Here is what you can add to your code to add the markers (put this in before the infowindow code).  You'll want to work with the [MarkerImage](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#MarkerImage) class to get the right anchors for the icons.

```
var image = 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/orZ4x.png';
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: pos,
        map: map,
        icon: image
    });  
marker.setMap(map);

var image = 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/KOh5X.png';
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: pos,
    map: map,
    icon: image
});  
marker.setMap(map);
```

Comment: Okay that's awesome :) So how would I go about doing the part where you hover and see the tooltip saying `You're here!` Thanks very much.

Comment: Add an event listener to the marker: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/events.html#EventListeners  --  So you'd use the `mouseover` event for the marker: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#Marker

Answer (score 1):

you can do in one marker using some if statements

```
  var image = '';

           if (product.category_id == 1) {

                   image = 'images/custom_category_1_icon.png';

           }

           else if (product.category_id == 2) {

                   image = 'images/custom_category_1_icon.png';

           }

           ....

           else if (product.category_id == N) {

                   image = 'images/custom_category_N_icon.png';

           }
```

//   and the marker here

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
position: pos,
map: map,
icon: image
});  
marker.setMap(map);
```